# How to Handle Application Errors in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am currently wondering how to handle application errors in Apache Flink streaming applications. In general, I see two cases:

1. Transient errors, where you want the input data to be replayed and processing might succeed on second try. An example would be a dependency on an external service, which is temporarily unavailable.
2. Permanent errors, where repeated processing will still fail; for example invalid input data.

For the first case, it looks like the common solution is to just throw some exception. Or is there a better way, e.g. a special kind of exception for more efficient handling such as `FailedException` from Apache Storm *Trident* (see [Error handling in Storm Trident topologies](https://svendvanderveken.wordpress.com/2014/02/05/error-handling-in-storm-trident-topologies/)).

For permanent errors, I couldn't find any information online. A `map()` operation, for example, always has to return something so one cannot just silently drop messages as you [would](https://svendvanderveken.wordpress.com/2014/02/05/error-handling-in-storm-trident-topologies/) in *Trident*.

What are the available APIs or best practices? Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI: [How to handle errors in custom MapFunction correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085646/how-to-handle-errors-in-custom-mapfunction-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked, there has been some development:

This [discussion](http://apache-flink-mailing-list-archive.1008284.n3.nabble.com/Discuss-FLIP-13-Side-Outputs-in-Flink-td14204.html) holds the background of [why side outputs should help](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-13+Side+Outputs+in+Flink), key extract:

> Side outputs(a.k.a Multi-outputs)  is one of highly requested features
> in high fidelity stream processing use cases. With this feature, Flink
> can
>
> - Side output corrupted input data and avoid job fall into “fail -> restart -> fail” cycle
> - Side output sparsely received late arriving events while issuing aggressive watermarks in window computation.

This resulted in jira: [FLINK-4460](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-4460) which has been resolved in Flink 1.1.3 and above.

---

I hope this helps, if an even more generic solution would be desireable, please think a bit on your usecase and consider to create a jira for it.

Comment: I have to admit that it's been a while since I wrote Flink quote and thought about this question. From my impression, Side Outputs do in fact look useful. However, they are only available for the generic `ProcessFunction` and its relatives. There still appears to be no good way of error handling for a simple `Map`.